# How to align modal window in center

Tags: html, css, ui-design

[Unable to place the modal window (popup), vertically center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yStib.png)I want to align the modal window in the center of the screen, but unable to do that. Here is my code (it's a part of React.JS application)

```
<div className="popup">
  <Modal open={this.state.show} onClose={this.handleClose}>
    <h1 className="text-center">
      <HorizontalBar data={horizontalBarData} options={ horizontalBarDataOptions} width="500" height="300" />
    </h1>

    <div className="wrapper">
      <CsvDownloader filename="myfile" columns={downloadColumn} datas={downloadData} text="DOWNLOAD" />
    </div>
  </Modal>
</div>
```

```css
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50% !important;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">
  <h1 class="text-center">
    Heading
  </h1>

  <div class="wrapper">
    stuff here
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: In what way is this not working?

Comment: It's working fine for me. https://jsfiddle.net/hb7ocpkL/

Comment: This should work Ashish, do you have a screenshot of how it appears for you?

Comment: Mihali Minkov, I have added the screenshot in my post. Please do check and suggest.

Comment: Works for me aswell

Comment: Perhaps clear your cache or check it in a private window.

Comment: I am not sure 100% how the generation works, but, what does `Modal` generate as code? Because from what you can see in the snippet, the code works fine, what might be different in your case is the code structure of the resulting code.